# Kali linux installation problem with partitions

Tags: boot, partition, hard-disk

I am trying to install Kali linux on my PC. I would like to have a dual boot but the problem is, when I want to make the manual partitioning step(Graphical Install) , the first SSD, where the Windows is installed is shown normally, but the HDD is shown with no partitions, the entire HDD is shown even if I made a partition on the HDD to install Kali linux on as you can see on the fist picture attached.

[image: Disk 1, Kali K: partition is made]

[image: HDD not showing Kali partition in on installer]

Comment: Hello and welcome on Unix & LInux Stack Exchange, please feel free to take a [tour]. Your question is quiet unclear, it's normal that partition from linux are not seen on windows. Could you please try to explain what you've done already what you want to do and what is not working for you at the moment so we can help a bit more. [Edit] your question please or it might get close because unclear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 3):

Your second disk is configured as a Dynamic Disk. That's less like partitioning and more like "LVM for Windows". And no, it's not compatible with Linux LVM.

There is [ldmtool](https://michael-prokop.at/blog/2013/02/18/ldmtool-accessing-microsoft-windows-dynamic-disks-from-linux/) which can allow accessing a dynamic disk from Linux; however, I don't think any distribution supports using a dynamic disk as a system disk (i.e. no support for booting Linux from a dynamic disk).

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory, but I see that your disk has several NTFS partitions labelled as "dynamic" on your device explorer in Windows, including your Kali partition.

It's quite possible that the Kali installer has no NTFS drivers (it's detecting the whole disk as a FAT32 partition). Make a regular partition (no dinamic) for Kali and don't create  any filesystem (or make a FAT32, or even better, EXT4 if you can from Windows) and try again.